# Exception In Initializer caused by Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, exception, jbutton, initializer

I have no idea why this is happening, but one day it was fine. Now, I try to run the code and I get an `ExceptionInInitializerError`. Here is the line that gets it:

```
final JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at program.gui.Chat.<init>(Chat.java:44)
        at program.gui.GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:176)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:19
95)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
a:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242
)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:8
09)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMen
uItemUI.java:850)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessCo
ntrolContext.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessCo
ntrolContext.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessCo
ntrolContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GPAMaster.locale.Locale.get(Locale.java:30)
        at GPAMaster.locale.Messages$Chat.<clinit>(Messages.java:84)
        ... 39 more
```

Comment: did you make an upgrade of java ?

Comment: I have the latest version of java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's *actually* a problem in the static constructor for `Messages.Chat`. Look into Messages.java line 84 and Locale.java line 30. Those are the relevant lines - your `Chat` GUI is somewhat irrelevant, I suspect.

Without seeing that code it's hard to guess exactly what's wrong, but it could be something like not having all the localized messages for your locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a string hint of the problem down at the bottom of that stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
GPAMaster.locale.Locale.get(Locale.java:30)
    at GPAMaster.locale.Messages$Chat.<clinit>(Messages.java:84)
    ... 39 more
```

So this means you've got a class named `Chat` nested in a class named `Messages`, and at line 84, you call `Locale.get()`, which is getting a `NullPointerException` at line 30. The method `<clinit>` is the *static initializer* for the class `Chat` -- it's a compiler-generated method that contains any static blocks or initializers for static methods.

If you show us `Messages.java` around line 84, and `Locale.java` around line 30, we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

this are the key statements from the exception

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GPAMaster.locale.Locale.get(Locale.java:30)
        at GPAMaster.locale.Messages$Chat.<clinit>(Messages.java:84)
        ... 39 more`:

You have a Null pointer in some static initialization code which is called before your constructor...  Resolve this issue and it should work again :)